# API Fetch returns nil

Tags: swift, alamofire

The fetch doesn't throw any error, it just returns nil, I don't know why, this is the api URL:

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true&include_24hr_change=true&include_last_updated_at=true
```

Note: There is an infinite amount of tokens, not only Bitcoin, so I can't hardcode it.

it looks like:

```
{
    "bitcoin": {
        "usd": 51110,
        "usd_market_cap": 964544028181.903,
        "usd_24h_vol": 19080677597.123028,
        "usd_24h_change": 2.163373654971005,
        "last_updated_at": 1640575480
    },
    thereCanBeMoreWhichIcan'tPredict: {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the model I created:

```
struct TokenSimplePriceCoingeckoUsdModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let usd, usd_market_cap, usd_24h_vol, usd_24h_change: Double?
    let last_updated_at: Int?
}
```

and this is how I'm fetching it with Alamofire:

```
func afRequest(url: URL) async throws -> Data {
    try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        // If another error try lowering the request error: (statusCode: 200..<300)
        // timeoutInterval is in seconds
        AF.request(url, method: .get, requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = .infinity }).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseData { response in
            
            if let data = response.data {
                continuation.resume(returning: data)
                return
            }
            
            if case let .failure(error) = response.result {
                print(" Error on afRequest(): \(error)")
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

func getDataFromAPI(url: String) async -> Any {
    do {
        let url = URL(string: url)!
        let undecodedData = try await afRequest(url: url)
        let finalData = try JSONDecoder().decode(TokenSimplePriceCoingeckoUsdModel.self, from: undecodedData)
        
        return finalData
    } catch(let error) {
        print(" Error on getDataFromAPI(): ", error)
    }
    return ""
}
```

When I print the return of that I get:

```
TokenSimplePriceCoingeckoUsdModel(usd: nil, usd_market_cap: nil, usd_24h_vol: nil, usd_24h_change: nil, last_updated_at: nil)
```

EDIT: If I do:

`print(String(data: undecodedData, encoding: .utf8)!)` under the line `let undecodedData ...` it prints the data, so it's confirmed the problem is while decoding it with my Model, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used alamofire directly to make a network request, but seems the error is on how you decode the response, assuming `undecodedData` is already containing the data you want, your current response model does not decode the "bitcoin" key, hence the struct is nil, you can change your struct to something like

```
struct BitcoinStats: Codable, Hashable {
    let bitcoin: TokenSimplePriceCoingeckoUsdModel
}

struct TokenSimplePriceCoingeckoUsdModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let usd, usd_market_cap, usd_24h_vol, usd_24h_change: Double?
    let last_updated_at: Int?
}
```

or you might want to try to decode the value of the "bitcoin" key directly, so you can keep your current struct as is

UPDATE :
Because the JSON has other keys than "bitcoin", this is my proposed solution for decoding the data dynamically without the needs to hardcode the keys:
[pastecode.io/s/tkim2jf0](https://pastecode.io/s/tkim2jf0)

Comment: I can't hardcode the token (bitcoin) like that because it will change. I only put 1 for simplisity, but look at this request: `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=tether%2Cwmatic%2Cethereum%2Cmoonriver&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true&include_24hr_change=true&include_last_updated_at=true` as you can see it can contain an infinite amount

Comment: If so, you can try to decode them as dictionary, i've added a working example based on your JSON here https://pastecode.io/s/tkim2jf0 @Albert

Comment: Hi @Albert, kindly let me know whether it works on your case or not, if not we're going to try another way

Comment: I was testing it now, it doesn't work :/ I tried this: `let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coin.self, from: undecodedData.data(using: .utf8)!)` and I get `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'utf8'` and `Value of type 'Data' has no member 'data'` Also how would I assign all that string to the model without doing extra calculations?

Comment: no, i was using .data(using: .utf8)! because my data is String, in your case
you can directly decode JSONDecoder().decode(Coin.self, from: undecodedData)

Comment: With that I'm getting this: `valueNotFound(Swift.Float, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "polyplay", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "usd_24h_change", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Float value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: after you decoded them, you can use them like this, here's the snippet https://pastecode.io/s/wwsk488t
notice the code inside the do block

Comment: do you update your struct? i didnt see any "polyplay" attribute before

Comment: Oh it seem to work with this line: `let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coin.self, from: undecodedData)` the error I posted above was because I had to mark the `Float` as optional. Thank you now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Your values are within a `bitcoin` object, so you need to decode that as well. You can start with this struct from quicktype.io:

```swift
struct Prices: Decodable {
    let bitcoin: Bitcoin
}

// MARK: - Bitcoin
struct Bitcoin: Decodable {
    let usd: Int
    let usdMarketCap, usd24HVol, usd24HChange: Double
    let lastUpdatedAt: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case usd
        case usdMarketCap = "usd_market_cap"
        case usd24HVol = "usd_24h_vol"
        case usd24HChange = "usd_24h_change"
        case lastUpdatedAt = "last_updated_at"
    }
}
```

Then you can use Alamofire 5.5's new `async` methods to automatically decode it:

```swift
let response = await AF.request(url).serializingDecodable(Prices.self).response
```

Comment: Please read the comment I left for @sushitrash, I can't hardcode Bitcoin because there is an infinite amount of coins, how can I make it more flexible?

Comment: Unless those keys are all named `bitcoin` they don't matter.

Comment: And looking at the documentation for the `simple` endpoint, that isn't true anyway. https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation

Comment: If I try that it says: `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "bitcoin", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"bitcoin\", intValue: nil) (\"bitcoin\").", underlyingError: nil))`